# How can I dump a string in perl to see if there are any character differences?

Tags: perl, unicode, encoding, character-encoding, dump

I've occasionally had problems with strings being subtly different, in some cases [utf8::all](https://metacpan.org/module/utf8%3a%3aall) changed the behavior, so I assume the subtle differences are unicode. I'd like to dump strings in such a way that the differences will be visual to me. What are my options for doing this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I recommend the `Dump` function in [the `Devel::Peek` module in the Perl core](http://perldoc.perl.org/Devel/Peek.html):

```
$ perl -MDevel::Peek -e 'Dump "abc"'
SV = PV(0x10441500) at 0x10491680
  REFCNT = 1
  FLAGS = (PADTMP,POK,READONLY,pPOK)
  PV = 0x10442224 "abc"\0
  CUR = 3
  LEN = 4

$ perl -MDevel::Peek -e 'Dump "\x{FEFF}abc"'
SV = PV(0x10441050) at 0x10443be0
  REFCNT = 1
  FLAGS = (PADTMP,POK,READONLY,pPOK,UTF8)
  PV = 0x10449bc0 "\357\273\277abc"\0 [UTF8 "\x{feff}abc"]
  CUR = 6
  LEN = 8
```

(You see how `FLAGS` contains `UTF8` in the second example, because of the wide character, but not in the first?)

Comment: Devel::Peek works other thigns done't because there are actually no special chars in the string but UTF8 flag is there.

Answer (score 4):

For most uses, [Data::Dumper](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Data::Dumper) with `Useqq` will do.

```
use utf8;
use Data::Dumper;
local $Data::Dumper::Useqq = 1;
print(Dumper("foo–bar"));
print(Dumper("foo-bar"));
```

Output:

```
$VAR1 = "foo\x{2013}bar";
$VAR1 = "foo-bar";
```

If you want internal details (such as the UTF8 flag), use [Devel::Peek](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Devel::Peek).

```
use utf8;
use Devel::Peek;
Dump("foo–bar");
Dump("foo-bar");
```

Output:

```
SV = PV(0x328ccc) at 0x1d6a0c4
  REFCNT = 1
  FLAGS = (PADTMP,POK,READONLY,pPOK,UTF8)
  PV = 0x1d6d52c "foo\342\200\223bar"\0 [UTF8 "foo\x{2013}bar"]
  CUR = 9
  LEN = 12
SV = PV(0x328dcc) at 0x32b594
  REFCNT = 1
  FLAGS = (PADTMP,POK,READONLY,pPOK)
  PV = 0x1d6d50c "foo-bar"\0
  CUR = 7
  LEN = 12
```

Comment: The Devel::Peek hyperlink is broken. Is it perhaps http://search.cpan.org/~shay/perl-5.24.1/ext/Devel-Peek/Peek.pm ?

Comment: @Nagev, Fixed the link

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried [Test::LongString](https://www.metacpan.org/module/Test%3a%3aLongString)? Even though it's really a test module, it is handy for showing you where the differences in a string occur. It focuses on the parts that are different instead of showing you the whole string, and it make `\x{}` escapes for specials.

I'd like to see an example where `utf8::all` changed the behavior, even if just to see an interesting edge case.

Comment: it involved password hashing, and databases. It was not fun, and I never figured out the why of it. Otherwise I would.

Comment: note: not sure that it was utf8::all before, but [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9780780/206466) seems to be my problem

Answer (score 1):

All you need to dump out any string is:

```
printf "U+%v04X\n", $string;
```

You could use this to format a string:

```
($print_string = $string) =~ s/([^\x20-\x7E])/sprintf "\\x{%x}", $1/ge;
```

or even

```
use charnames ();
($print_string = $string) =~ s/([^\x20-\x7E])/sprintf "\\N{%s}", charnames::viacode(ord $1)/ge;
```

I have no idea why in the wolrd you would use the misleadingly named `utf8::all`.  It’s not a core module, and you seem to be having some sort of trouble with knowing what it is really doing. If you explicitly used the individual core pieces that go into it, maybe you would understand it all better.

Comment: what I never figured out with my problem previously was where or even how it was happening. various places with various magic monkeying my works, e.g. dancer plugin database turning on utf8, iirc

Comment: all I know is that I input 'foo' in spot A, and got sha X, and I input it in spot B and I got sha Y, consistently. I added utf8::all to the module and problem went away. I don't like not understanding it at all.